# AirConsole View Manager is not defined after uploading for testing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, airconsole

I'm currently building a game, when I tried uploading it to AirConsole the game gives me a error in the preview.

Has anyone had this problem before?

"Uncaught ReferenceError: AirConsoleViewManager is not defined".

```
var airconsole = new AirConsole({ "orientation": "landscape", "device_motion": 10 });
    var vm = null;
    window.onload = start;

    airconsole.onReady = function () {
        //THE LINE UNDER CRASHES
        vm = new AirConsoleViewManager(airconsole);
    };


ReferenceError: AirConsoleViewManager is not defined
at AirConsole.airconsole.onReady (https://storage.googleapis.com/XXX.xxxxxxx.xxxx.cdn.airconsole.com/2018-05-24-16-33-25/controller.html:125:22)
at AirConsole.onPostMessage_ (https://www.airconsole.com/api/airconsole-latest.js:1053:8)
at https://www.airconsole.com/api/airconsole-latest.js:969:8
```

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what the problem was, but after cleaning the build and transfering code over to another project, then uploading again it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you got the information about AirConsoleViewManager from [here](https://github.com/AirConsole/airconsole-view-manager) (GitHub).

I can't tell for sure because you haven't linked the entire file, but you need to download the **airconsole-view-manager.js** and include that in your controller script.

The example from the previously linked GitHub example is kind of weird because it doesn't include the JS file in it. Most likely the reason for this is that they assume (which you should never do as a developer) people know it already.

> **EDIT:** Actually, they do include the file but it's not done in JS file, it's in HTML file:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="airconsole-view-manager.js"></script>`